# Java faster than C?

Tags: java, c, arrays, performance, sorting

Everything I had heard so far is people saying Java is generally slower than C, with some exceptions (Like involving code that does nothing).  So I went out to test it.  I had an array of 100,000 integers between 0 and 999,999.  I used a double for loop to sort them from smallest to largest, in both C and java (compiled on OS X).

The results were Java generally finishing in half the time.  Out of 5 runs with different arrays Java took around 17 seconds while C took around 32 seconds (That includes the time allocating and populating the array from a file which for both was negligible).

So what would have made the Java code run faster than C? Is there something I'm missing, or some underlying technology I've heard nothing about?

Edit:  Also not sure if it matters, but I timed it using the time command, not any custom code. Ex: `$time java SortArray`

And as for compiler options, I can't access that command line right now, but it was default gcc options on OS X 10.10:

**`gcc sortarray.c -o sortarray`**

And I just used default javac to compile the Java.

**`javac SortArray.java`**

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 32

int main()
{
    FILE* file = fopen("bigarray.txt", "r");
    int arraySize = 100000;
    int array[100000] = {};
    int i, j, temp;
    char inputBuffer[SIZE];
    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        fgets(inputBuffer, SIZE, file);
        array[i] = strtod(inputBuffer, NULL);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        for (j = i + 1; j < arraySize; j++)
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }

    for (i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        printf("%d, ", array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SortArray {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("bigarray.txt"));

    int[] array = new int[100000];
    for(int i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        array[i] = s.nextInt();
    }


    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] > array[j]) {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Where have you heard that? It's almost always the opposite being said. Right or wrong, C is the gold standard for speed.

Comment: Java is *not* faster then C. Care to post your code? You're probably doing something inefficiently.

Comment: Ah, yes, the ol' benchmark wars!!  This battle has been going on for maybe 20 years now.  Depending on the context, either one can "win".  But it suffices to say that "the performance is lousy" is not a valid reason to reject Java as a programming language.  Performance is far more dependent on the function being performed and how well the programmer matches the implementation to the resources at hand.

Comment: I think the first sentence is meant to read "saying Java is generally slower than C"

Comment: Java *can* be faster than C [in *certain* benchmarks](http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/java.php). Overall: no (although it is well within a factor unlike some dynamic languages), in specific cases: yes.

Comment: Shows us your code. Your single point result doesn't mean a thing unless they can be reproduced and examined in a broader context.

Comment: Also provide the compiler options you used with the code. When talking about performance compiler options can be very important.

Comment: Ok well I added my code and (generally) what compilers I used, since I can't check right now.

Comment: @cclloyd Just saw and wrote a short answer. Your comparison is flawed since Java optimized by default while gcc doesn't. When you use optimizations in your C code it should be fairer.

Comment: ... Which is the language that has been used to write the powerful Java capabilities (Like JIT and others)!!? :) I think C or C++ then ...

Answer (score 11):

Your comparison of their runtime is unfair and flawed. You use default compiler options but Java and C differ on what optimizations they enable by default. And in general measuring performance without optimizations turned on is completely useless of itself, the output could completely change in the real world depending on which can be optimized more.

Java uses a JIT to optimize your code while it runs even with default options.

For gcc the default optimization option is `-O0` which means there weren't any optimizations done at all. Try using `-O2` or `-O3` for a more fair comparison.

For example results on my machine are:

- C code with default compiler options = 12.5secs.
- C code with `-O3` to enable optimization = 4.5secs.
- Java code = 8.5 secs.

Comment: Why does the C sort chars instead of integers like the array is?

Answer (score 2):

They are 2 different languages in design, and should be treated as such.

C is a low-level, executable-compiled language, that can do low-level hardware operations such as dynamic memory allocation, and accessing hardware drivers at a very low level. C is normally faster than Java, if it is written efficiently, but it always depends on the compiler. Some compilers support optimization on the compile time, to produce more efficient code, by removing redundant code and other unnecessary artefacts.

One reason that people say C is faster is because you can do allot more with it, such as use low-level multi threading, memory allocation (Via `malloc`), and other operations that could speed up the program's operation considerably.

Java, on the other hand, is compiled to JVM bytecode, which depends entirely on the JVM (Written in C++) for it's speed. Java has allot less low-level functionality than C, and therefore loses speed in some cases, where C would run allot faster.

Overall, the general reasons your program could lose performance in C is the fact that you

1. Used a bad compiler
2. Wrote inefficient code
3. Used slower functions, structures, etc.

But, in most cases, C normally runs considerably faster, and is known to have that over Java, which is one reason it lies at the core of most operating systems, and other advanced software.

Answer (score 1):

first of all it is totally wrong to compare languages, sometimes you can compare compilers for the same language, but not languages itself

anyway, java could be faster just because it has JIT, which means during run-time java gathers some statistics and could perform additional optimizations or caching which are almost impossible with c compilers

though some c compilers have profiler-guided optimization loop and final result of such optimization will/could run faster neither java code

Comment: Yes but C doesn't need JIT ... A C program, when compiled, is already compiled ... Java is "interpreted", precompiled if you want, but uses another software that act using the code! A compiled C is already what the CPU want! ...

Comment: @SergioFormiggini yes, what is your point?

Comment: My point is about speed ... It is quite obvious that a C code is faster than a Java code. The problem may be seen on the basis of the advantage to use Java versus C that depends on what is to be developed!

Comment: @SergioFormiggini you're wrong, java application could run faster neither c one, I've explained when it is possible in answer

Comment: I.E. I've tried to develop a program to compute a lot of prime numbers. I made it in Java and in C. What's the faster on your opinion?

Comment: But I think that for applications Java is a good way because has more functionality than C! But for MCUs, at now, the best way is C and sometimes assembler!

Comment: It's no way to demonstrate that Java is faster than C! It's not possible! The only way a Java function is faster than a C function is that the C function was written in a wrong way!!! That's all!!!

Comment: I think it would intersting a challenge with simple program ... :)

Comment: An other add ... Which is the language that has been used to write the powerful Java capabilities (Like JIT and others)!!?

Comment: @SergioFormiggini check out this question and answer to find out when java is faster http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29656648/java-8-times-faster-with-arrays-than-stdvector-in-c-what-did-i-do-wrong

Comment: I've downloaded the code! Is true, java seems faster of the C++ code that uses STL vectors ... Why does the C++ code use STL vectors and doesn't use bool array as is in the Java code? ... I think this is the trick! I think if the code will be written in C is faster!

Comment: At now, I have to accept that with this code Java is faster ... I think that the problem might be something about the FP ... I will investigate!

Comment: If we're talking purely theory, a JIT has some potential advantages that a statically-compiled language doesn't. For example, it might be able unroll a loop of N iterations, where N is a runtime value determined by user input, but can be guaranteed to be a constant within a given context. In practice, the theoretical advantages of a JIT are often outweighed by more practical things. In that example shown, `vector<bool>` is a slow but memory-saving version compressing each byte to a single bit. It's an extremely flawed comparison, and an array of bools/vector<char> is typically vastly faster.

Comment: I don't really notice the speed difference, but what I notice is that the every time a Java IDE or some program runs the PC fan goes high and all the CPU's are close to max.