# Java : Counting so fast?

Tags: java

This code in my PC performed 1 sec in java, but more than 20 sec in C .How does java perform like this?

```
int a[] = new int[50000] ; 
for(int i = 0 ; i < 50000 ; i++) { 
    for(int j = 0 ; j < 200000 ; j++) a[i] = j - i ;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java faster than C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662971/java-faster-than-c)

Comment: 1 sec is a long time for doing nothing. From a style perspective: its not a very good idea to clutter your code with lines of code that do nothing even if it makes no difference. It tend to confuse you as this question proves. Yes, looks like the C compiler in oposite to Java seems to execute this noop code. Which is not realy a surprise.

Answer (score 1):

Java sees that your code doesn't do anything and optimizes it to do nothing faster (as the comments suggest). When I run the code as is it completes in 0.33 seconds. With this simple change it takes 17 seconds:

```
public class Test {
    public static volatile int b;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = new int[50000] ; 
        for(int i = 0 ; i < 50000 ; i++) { 
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 200000 ; j++) {
                a[i] = j - i ;
                b = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As b is volatile the runtime can no longer optimize away the unused assignments. Micro-benchmarks are mostly useless in my view as the real-world results depend on so many different things, but knowing how the JVM works is always good!

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but imo even in that case the array should not be populated. (I'd regard it as a runtime  bug if it were). b=j - i ; without array should give the same result.